# Legend position for figures with variable size

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, legend, subplot

My plot function creates horizontal bars per year for data with different size. I have to change the figure size for each set of subplots.
I need to place my two legends on lower center of each figure below the x axis label. The positions need to vary depending on the figure size and remain consistent. So for all produced figures, the legends would look like this [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5ZQ2.png).

Find a snippet of my dataframe [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZVca.png). I have tried to simplify the code as much as I could and I know the plot is missing some element, but I just want to get to my question's answer, not to create a perfect plot here. I understand probably I need to create a variable for my anchor bounding box but I don't know how. Here is my code:

```
def plot_bars(data,ax):
    """ Plots a single chart of work plan for a specific routeid
    data: dataframe with section length and year
    Returns: None"""
    ax.barh(df['year'], df['sec_len'] , left = df['sec_begin'])
    ax.set_yticklabels('')
def plot_fig(df):
    # Draw the plots
    ax_set = df[['routeid','num_bars']].drop_duplicates('routeid')
    route_set = ax_set['routeid'].values
    h_ratios = ax_set['num_bars'].values
    len_ratio = h_ratios.sum()/BARS_PER_PAGE # Global constant set to 40 based on experiencing 

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(route_set), 1, squeeze=False, sharex=True
                           , gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':h_ratios}
                           , figsize=(10.25,7.5*len_ratio))
    
    for i, r in enumerate(route_set):
            plot_bars(df[df['routeid']==r], axes[i,0])
    plt.xlabel('Section length')
    ## legends
    fig.legend(labels=['Legend2'], loc=8, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.45))

    fig.legend( labels=['Legend1'], loc = 8, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.3))

    ## Title
    fig.suptitle('title', fontsize=16, y=1)
    fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0, top = 1-0.03/len_ratio)

for df in df_list:
    plot_fig(df)
```

The problem is when the figure size changes, the legends move as in these pictures:

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3Mla.png)

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhLXb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem boils down to having the correct relative position with respect to the `xlabel`, so are right that you need to calculate the `bbox_to_anchor` using the position of the xlabel and the height/width of the axes. Something like this:

```py
fig, (ax, ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(5, 4), gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[4, 1]})


ax.plot(range(10), range(10), label="myLabel")
ax.set_xlabel("xlabel")

x, y = ax.xaxis.get_label().get_position() # position of xlabel
h, w = ax.bbox.height, ax.bbox.width # height and width of the Axes

leg_pos = [x + 0 / w, y - 55 / h] # this needs to be adjusted according to your needs
fig.legend(loc="lower center", bbox_to_anchor=leg_pos, bbox_transform=ax.transAxes)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Because I need two legends, I cannot use `ax.legend`. I believe an axis can have only one legend. I have to use `fig.legend` as stated in the question and then set its `bbox_transform = ax1.transAxes`. After that it worked perfectly. @krm Please edit your answer so I can set it as the correct answer.

Comment: Done! If you do want to use multiple legends on `Axes`, there is a way: See https://riptutorial.com/matplotlib/example/32429/multiple-legends-on-the-same-axes. But your way seems better for sure